# Should I validate the values loaded from configuration files?

Tags: configuration

One application loads config values from external XML files. These XML files are ***not*** ***supposed*** to be modified by users directly. But should be modified within the application.

The question is, there's no way to prevent user from finding and modifying the XML files. And the modification can be incorrect/malicious.

Should I validate the values when loading into the application? Or any other best practice? Or should I just document it and blame user for mis-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is that you should *always* validate the contents of a configuration file. Doing so means your application will be adhering to the [Fail Fast principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast). Whether you want to hand-code your own validation checks from scratch or use an off-the-shelf [XML schema validation language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema#Languages) to automate some/most/all the checks is of lesser importance.